# "/usr/sbin/sendmail/" Not found

Tags: email, ubuntu

Locally a Rail app works well, but on a VPS server when I try to send an email with all the correct settings by the means of the Rails app, I get this error in the logs:

```
sh: 1: /usr/sbin/sendmail: not found
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 76):

You need to install the `sendmail` package on your VPS as well as your local machine. Assuming you use some form of Debian linux, you want to run:

```
sudo apt-get install sendmail
```

on the VPS.

Comment: consider @Will's answer instead of using this sendmail approach. sendmail configuration is not evident

Answer (score 22):

You need to install a Mail Transport Agent (MTA).

First, let's install `postfix`, which provides a `/usr/bin/sendmail`:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install postfix
```

A configuration screen will pop up, where you need to enter some configuration values. This really depends on your setup. The standard installation is "Internet site", where mail will be sent directly from your server. You can also configure it to relay mail through an external mailserver, which may be preferable if you don't want to deal with SPF, TLS, reverse DNS, etc. But the specifics of the configuration is outside the scope of this question (just Google it, or post a new question if you get stuck).

Comment: why not install sendmail?

Comment: You can, but `postfix` is a bit more modern, and far easier to configure :)

Comment: @OskarK. "sendmail look alike for SENDING email" is provided by almost any unix/linux MTA (sendmail/postfix/exim/...).  Installation of "sendmail original" is not necessary the best choice for "your first MTA ever".

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip, I don't understand anything.

Comment: @Will, what config does it require? besides, I'm using gmail to send an email, why would I need mta?

Comment: @OskarK. To get /usr/sbin/sendmail install one of many available MTA packages e.g. sendmail, postfix, exim, ...

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip, ok, but why does sending an email via gmail require that?

Comment: @user266003 for sending your own email via GMail, you do not need an MTA. Your rails app, however, uses a service installed on that system to send emails. That is the MTA. If you have an MTA on that VPS, all scripts, apps, processes can easily send emails via that "sendmail" command (that all MTAs provide). You must configure the MTA to send the emails correctly, one option is to configure it to use GMail to send emails.